# How to detect cell value changed datagridview c#

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

There does not seem to be a definitive answer for similar questions on SOF.

I have a `DataGridView` that is bound to a `BindingList<T>` object (which is a list of custom objects; also inherits `INotifyPropertyChanged`). The custom objects each have a unique timer. When those timer's pass a certain value (say 10 seconds), I want to change the cell's forecolor to red.

I am using the `CellValueChanged` event, but this event never seems to fire, even though I can see the timer changing on the `DataGridView`. Is there a different event I should be looking for? Below is my `CellValueChanged` handler.

```
private void checkTimerThreshold(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0,0,10);
        if (e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0)
            return;
        if (orderObjectMapping[dataGridView1["OrderID", e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()].getElapsedStatusTime().CompareTo(ts) > 0)
        {
            DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
            cellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style = cellStyle;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't make it 100% clear what you are trying to do. I'm going to answer based on my best guess but could you edit your question to make it clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. The user does no editing. A CSV file is constantly being parsed to add/update/delete objects from the BindingList<T>. Say I start the program, and there is only one row in the DGV. I will see the timer increment every second, and when it passes 10 seconds, I want to change the colour of the text to red.

Comment: Just edited my answer with something that should work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way this I know of to make the DataGridView raise an event when its DataSource is programatically changed - this is by design.

The best way I can think of to meet your requirement is to introduce a BindingSource into the mix - binding sources do raise events when their DataSource changes.

Something like this works (you will obviously need to fine tune it to your needs):

```
bindingSource1.DataSource = tbData;
dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
bindingSource1.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(bindingSource1_ListChanged); 

public void bindingSource1_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle(); 
    cellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;

    dataGridView1.Rows[e.NewIndex].Cells[e.PropertyDescriptor.Name].Style = cellStyle;
}
```

Another option to to do this by subscribing directly to the data - if it is a BindingList it will propogate the NotifyPropertyChanged events using its own ListChanged event. In a more MVVM scenario that would possibly be cleaner but in WinForms the BindingSource is probably best.

Comment: Sorry it took so long but thanks! I used the NotifyPropertyChanged events and everything works perfectly now!