# Datagrid change cell color when value changes

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, colors, cell

I know how to change the textcolor of cells when the datagrid is populated using a converter, but I can't find anything related to changing the textcolor after the cell value has been changed in certain value. I need to do this from code since the values I need to check with are not always the same.

```
public class NameToBrushConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = values[0] as DataGridCell;
        Session_Counter.CoreWindow.BindableDynamicDictionary row = values[1] as Session_Counter.CoreWindow.BindableDynamicDictionary;
        CoreWindow.Fields field = CoreWindow.fields.Find(o => o.name == cell.Column.Header.ToString());

        if (cell != null && row != null && field.color != null)
        {
            foreach (string str in field.color)
            {
                List<string> str2 = new List<string>(str.Split(new string[] { "<&p>" }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList());
                if (str2[0].ToString().StartsWith("VALUE = "))
                {
                    if (str2[0].Substring(8) == row[cell.Column.Header.ToString()].ToString())
                        return new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(str2[5]));
                }
            }
        }

        return Brushes.Black;
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dgwDataMain" CellEditEnding="dgwDataMain_CellEditEnding" SelectionChanged="dgwDataMain_SelectionChanged" PreviewKeyDown="dgwDataMain_PreviewKeyDown" CanUserAddRows="False" Grid.Row="2" Width="Auto" MaxColumnWidth="300" Height="Auto" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" >
                        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource nameToBC}">
                                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                            <Binding Path="."/>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#CCDAFF" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
                    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Have a look at the `BindingSource` Event you can change the color that way here is a good Stackoverflow answer that can give you the answer you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605608/how-to-detect-cell-value-changed-datagridview-c-sharp

Comment: see http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/203791/Changing-fore-color-of-a-dataGridView-cell